# Using attribute to identify entity in ractivejs in lists

Tags: ractivejs

```
function ListModel(listItems) {
    var self = this;
    this.name = "TestList";
    this.page = 0;
    this.maxPage = listItems.length / 10;
    this.items = function (pageNo) { return self.allItems.slice(pageNo * 10, (pageNo * 10) + 10); };
    this.allItems = listItems;
    this.nextPage = function() {
        this.set("page", self.page + 1);                
    }

    this.prevPage = function () {
        this.set("page", self.page - 1);
    }
}
```

Using this viewmodel I have successfully implemented paging with this template

```
<table>
    {{#items(page)}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{id}}</td>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{selectedItems}}" value="{{.}}" /> </td>
    </tr>
    {{/items}}
</table>

<h2> Selected ITEMS</h2>
<table>
    {{#selectedItems}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{id}}</td>
        <td>{{name}}</td>                    
    </tr>
    {{/selectedItems}}
</table>

<button disabled="{{!page}}" on-click="invoke(prevPage)">Prev</button><button disabled="{{!(page<maxPage -1)}}" on-click="invoke(nextPage)">Next</button>
```

The problem with this solution is that when I select an item in the list, the keypath( i belive) is used to identify the selected item, so when I click Next, then same itemes on the next page is selected. 
This is somewhat expected, but undesirable.

Is there some way to tell ractive that it should use e.g the Id property of the item as the identifier not the keypath, or have I doen something really stupid here?

Should this be solved in a completly different way?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, I think what you're trying to do is correct and there's a bug (see https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1610).

But you can work around by adding an index and correlate the selected items on that:

```
<table>
    {{#items(page):i}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{id}}</td>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{selectedItems}}" value="{{i}}" /> </td>
    </tr>
    {{/items}}
</table>

<h2> Selected ITEMS</h2>
<table>
    {{#selectedItems}}
    {{#items(page)[i]}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{id}}</td>
        <td>{{name}}</td>                    
    </tr>
    {{/items(page)[i]}}
    {{/selectedItems}}
</table>
```